# Google Analytics 4 - event count but no conversion count

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4, attribution

Has anyone encountered this problem? We have a couple of events that are showing up as events in GA4 like expected, we've marked them as conversions since many weeks back, but they are not showing up as conversions.

[image]

We have a server-side analytics setup with GTM and Google Tag that from what we can see works like expected. This issue makes us lose the attribution back to our paid traffic.

Edit: I found a workaround, which was to create a brand new GA4-property and route our server-side events through there instead. This new property works like expected without changing anything else in our server-side analytics setup.

Comment: Does the outgoing request from serverside GTM have the parameter "_c" with a value of "1"? This is how GA4 determines if the event is a conversion or not.

Comment: Yes, our tracking server fires a POST request to GA with the last couple of parameters being:
`sct=7&sid=1696514676&_c=1&ep.is_from_gtm=true&ep.cta_name=DOWNLOAD_APP_TIMESLOTCARD&en=boka_mote&_et=4237&seg=1&ep.cta_title=Boka%20m%C3%B6te&are=1`

Comment: Exact same problem here. We use server side GTM as well.